# How do I fix protocol in location header NGINX?

Tags: nginx-config

I have a problem with my response header for an SSL server.

Description:
I need to start my application on two protocols: HTTP and HTTPS. When I start my application on port 80, everything is okay; the location returns correctly. But when I try to start my application on SSL, some queries like GET return normally, but POST queries return with a header location in which the path to the server is incorrect. For instance, I start my application at https://10.10.10.10/main, then click on the button with POST queries and get redirected to HTTP. I have clearly indicated the following header in my Nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

but this doesn't help. When I start my application without port 80, everything works well.

```
CLIENT: GET https://10.10.10.10/main
NGINX RETURN: OPTIONS: http://10.10.10.10:443/api/upload-files?chunk_id=9
BACKEND RETURN: POST: http://10.10.10.10:443/api/upload-files?chunk_id=9 <-- ERROR
```

My request header for POST query:

```
POST /api/upload-files?chunk_id=9 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.10
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://10.10.10.10/main
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------219886506429414807063029689904
Content-Length: 49766
Origin: https://10.10.10.10
DNT: 1
Sec-GPC: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response headers for this query:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Server: nginx/1.25.4
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2024 16:05:49 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
location: http://10.10.10.10:443/api/upload-files/?chunk_id=9 <-- Why doesn't browser use https if port is 443???  
x-process-time: 0.0003325939178466797
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

Where is my mistake? I would be grateful for your help. Here is my full config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        client_max_body_size 50M;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;

        location /api/ws {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000/api/ws$is_args$args;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host ${NGINX_SERVER_PATH}:${NGINX_SERVER_PORT_HTTP};
            proxy_set_header Content-Type $http_content_type;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host ${NGINX_SERVER_PATH}:${NGINX_SERVER_PORT_HTTP};
            proxy_set_header Content-Type $http_content_type;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location / {
            include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type $http_content_type;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        client_max_body_size 50M;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/carrotocr.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/carrotocr.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/carrotocr.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location /api/ws {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000/api/ws$is_args$args;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host ${NGINX_SERVER_PATH}:${NGINX_SERVER_PORT_HTTPS};
            proxy_set_header Content-Type $http_content_type;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host ${NGINX_SERVER_PATH}:${NGINX_SERVER_PORT_HTTPS};
            proxy_set_header Content-Type $http_content_type;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }

        location / {
            include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type $http_content_type;
        }
    }
}
```

UPD:
I've understood significant point. If I add unnecessary symbol, for instance http://10.10.10.10/api/upload-files?chunk_id=9 together http://10.10.10.10/api/upload-files/?chunk_id=9 then I got options from uvicorn. Well, I found easy solution with path, but maybe somebody know how can I setting my nginx conf, that I get 'location' header with needful protocol?